# socket.io + angularjs ui-router + show message twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am creating a chat application using NodeJS and Express. In client side, i use angularjs,ui-router and socket.io. here i am use a master controller where initiate the socket and connect and show room list. when i click to room list, navigate to room through ui-router. it's OK for first time. but if i go to another room and get back to previous, message show multiple times.

Here show two user from same chat window

[image]

Comment: Some code would help but, to start, how are you recording that a person is in a certain room? You could be adding the same person more than once and then they receive the message multiple times when you broadcast to the room.

Comment: You need to edit your question with more code. But even so I think this will be hard to help you with, as it can be anything, you need to debug all places and see what is going on. Am not expert with angular but my guess is you can also debug the binding and see if something is done incorrectly. I will vote to close the question. Good luck